# Unmarshalling XML elements by attribute name versus tag name

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling, moxy

Here's the XML I'm trying to unmarshall:

```
<eveapi version="2" zkbapi="1">
  <result>
    <rowset name="events">
      <row eventID="41551776" solarSystemID="30003069">
        <pilot characterID="1803362092"/>
        <rowset name="copilots">
          <row characterID="914916227"/>
          <row characterID="877714973"/>
        </rowset>
        <rowset name="items">
          <row typeID="31055"/>
          <row typeID="2048"/>
        </rowset>
      </row>
    </rowset>
  </result>
</eveapi>
```

I'm having issues unmarshalling the two rowset tags copilots and items (the objects are null after the unmarshall).  Also, I have no control over the schema.  Below is the class that represents the  tag at the eveapi/result/rowset/row level.  Event is instantiated by jaxb.  Pilot is unmarshalled fine. But I can't get copilots and items to work, they are both null.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "row")
public class Event {

    @XmlElement(name = "pilot")
    Pilot pilot;

    @XmlPath("rowset[@name='copilots']")
    Copilots copilots;

    @XmlPath("rowset[@name='items']")
    Items items;
```

Is what I am doing possible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the `@XmlPath` annotation you need to be sure you are using [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) as your JAXB provider.  To do this you need to have EclipseLink on your classpath and a `jaxb.properties` file in the same package as your domain model with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

For more information see the following posts on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html

Comment: Funny, I skimmed your "Map to element based on attribute value" and completely missed the part on the jaxb.properties file being needed.  It was late at night.  Once I added it, everything worked great.  Thanks a lot.  And great blog, btw.